# VBA Access - Error en buscador de productos

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Estoy preparando un buscador de productos en una tabla. Quiero saber si hay algún producto al menos que cumpla con la condición dada.

Si en la entrada de la función pongo una 'c' quisiera saber si hay al menos algún registro que contenga una cadena de texto que tenga un carácter así. Por ejemplo: "casa", "camión", "arcón"...etc..

El código que he preparado es el siguiente:

```
Private Function VerificaProducto(ByVal Codigo, ByVal Familia, ByVal Proveedor) As String

Dim Horno As Database
Dim Panes As Recordset

Set Horno = CurrentDb

If Proveedor = "Cuetara" Then
    Set Panes = Horno.OpenRecordset("almacenpanes", dbOpenDynaset)

    If Familia Like "Integral" Then 
        Panes.FindFirst "codigo = ' " & "*" & Codigo & "*" & " ' and activo = true and tipo = 'Hidratos' and familia LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'"
    Else
        Panes.FindFirst "codigo = ' " & "*" & Codigo & "*" & " ' and activo = true and tipo = 'Hidratos' and familia NOT LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'"
    End If
End If
If Panes.NoMatch Then

    Me!NombreProducto = "CODIGO NO PRESENTE EN LAS TABLAS"

    VerificaProducto = "producto no encontrado"
Else
    VerificaProducto = "producto encontrado"
End If
End Function
```

Si se ha seleccionado un tipo de pan Integral, la función acotará la búsqueda a esos resultados: Sólo los registros de tipo integral. Si no, sólo a los que No son del tipo integral.

Entonces, debería ver si hay al menos un código que tenga parte del código introducido.

Sin embargo, parece que se toma la variable argumento código al pie de la letra y no busca las cadenas que puedan ser compatibles con ese código. ¿Alguien puede dar alguna pista de por qué?

Comment: Hola. En tu pregunta dices *...si hay algún producto al menos que cumpla con la condición dada...*. Entiendo que solamente quieres saber si hay productos que cumplen las condiciones que definas o no. Para ello, te sugiero usar directamente [DCont (función)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/DCont-funci%C3%B3n-F6B5D78B-AD0B-4E42-BE7A-11A64ACBF3D3). Respecto a tu pregunta. ¿qué tipo de variable es `Código`? ¿Qué valor tiene cuando ejecutas la función? Quizás debería ser `"codigo LIKE ' " & "*" & Codigo & "*" & " '`porque usando `=` lo toma literal.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, perdon por contestar 9 meses despues, espero aun sirva la respuesta:

Bueno de entrada, segun entiendo yo, tienes una tabla, y de la tala vas a buscar un producto segun la seleccion del usuario, la meta es que si el usuario typea "Pan" el sistema le recomiende una serie de productos...

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

1.- De entrada en mi opinión siento que seria buena idea realizar esto en un comboBox, y 
    en la propiedad del surce, colocaría la consulta de la tabla en el control, 
    seleccionando el Id del producto y la descripción.

2.- En el evento "Después de Actualizar" del control crearía una rutina con la misma 
    consulta del source pero con un LIKE, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT IdProducto, DescripcionProducto 
FROM Productos
WHERE DescripcionProducto LIKE '% " & Nz(Me.cmbFiltro, "") & " %'
```

Con esto lograras el cometido, de cuando el usuario escriba un fragmento de la palabra, le aparezcan las opciones que esten relacionadas con su busqueda.